# Using Cauchy sequence , show that this sequence converges

Tags: calculus, cauchy-sequences

Consider $\left(b_k\right)^{\infty }_{k=0}$ a sequence of integer numbers, and $a_{n\:=\:}\sum _{k=0}^n\:\frac{1}{k^2}\left(-1\right)^{b_k}$.
Using Cauchy theorem, How can i prove that this sequence converges?

So far i said:
Let $\epsilon >0$. we need to find an N such that for any $n,m > N$ , $\left|a_m-a_n\right|<\epsilon $.
So i want to evaluate $\left|a_m-a_n\right|$:
$\left|a_m-a_n\right|$  = $\left|\sum \:_{k=n+1}^m\:\frac{1}{k^2}\left(-1\right)^{b_k}\:\:\right|$ but from here i stuck, because we don't know what is $b_k$. tnx!

Comment: The series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Next step: Without loss of generality  are assuming $n\lt m$.  By the Triangle Inequality, $\left|\sum_{n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}(-1)^{b_n}\right|\le \sum_{n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}$. The step after that is to show that by taking $N$ large enough, we can make $\sum_{n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}\lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on
André Nicolas's comment,
which I upvoted
since it should have been
an answer,

$$\sum_{n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}
\le \sum_{n+1}^m \frac{1}{k(k-1)}
= \sum_{n+1}^m \left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)
= \frac1{n}-\frac1{m}
< \frac1{n}
$$
so the sum is Cauchy
since this upper bound
goes to zero
as $n$ and $m$
go to infinity.

Of course,
nothing in this answer
is original by me.

Comment: I like that your explanation requires no knowledge of the convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$. :-)

Comment: Your comment was *so* perceptive and insightful that I just *had* to upvote it:)

Answer (score 0):

First, prove $c_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges.

So ${c_n}$ is Cauchy; i.e. $\exists N$ such that $m \geq n > N$ implies $c_m - c_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \dots +  \frac{1}{m^2} < \epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon > 0.$ Therefore,

$$\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}(-1)^{b_k}\right| = \left| \frac{(-1)^{b_{n+1}}}{(n+1)^2} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^{b_{m}}}{m^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \dots +  \frac{1}{m^2} < \epsilon $$ if  $m \geq n > N$.